# Decréscimo JavaScript - imprimir lista ao contrario

Tags: javascript

Quero imprimir os valores de uma lista ao contrário, então a minha ideia foi a de começar a atribuir o valor a uma lista vazia a partir do ultimo elemento da lista de referencia. Porém a saída fica sendo a lista vazia... Eu não sei onde esta o erro.

```
listaReferencia= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
listaInversa = [];

for(var i = listaReferencia.length - 1; i <= 0; i--) {
    listaInversa.push(listaReferencia(i));
}

console.log(listaInversa);

Saída no console:
[]
```

Eu sinto que o erro deve estar em  (var i = listaReferencia.length - 1; i <= 0; i--)

Comment: Veja o método [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) que inverte os itens de um array in loco e também  retorna uma referencia ao array invertido. Ex: `console.log(listaReferencia.reverse());`

Comment: Sua pergunta não está executando o laço `for` da maneira que declarou a condição de iteração. Basta mudar o sinal para: `for(let i = listaReferencia.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`. Outra coisa é a maneira que acessa as variáveis no vetor deveria ser:  `listaInversa.push(listaReferencia[i]);`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo comentário de vocês!! Me ajudou muito, eu não tinha percebido esse erro no sinal e que tinha trocado [] por () para acessar a variável.